# Kafka and Zookeeper pods restart repeatedly on Kubernetes cluster

Tags: kubernetes, apache-kafka

I'm developing a microservices-based application deployed with Kubernetes for a university project. I'm newbie with Kubernetes and Kafka and I'm trying to run Kafka and zookeeper in the same minikube cluster. I have created one pod for Kafka and one pod for Zookeeper but after deploying them on the cluster they begin to restart repeatedly going to "CrashLoopBackOff" error. Taking a look at the logs I noticed that kafka launch a "ConnectException: Connection refused", it seems that kafka cannot establish connection with zookeeper. I have created the pods manually with the following config file:

**zookeeper-deploy.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: zookeeper
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: zookeeper
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: zookeeper
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: zookeeper
          image: bitnami/zookeeper
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 2181
          env:
            - name: ALLOW_ANONYMOUS_LOGIN
              value: "yes"

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: zookeeper
spec:
  selector:
    app: zookeeper
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 2181
```

**kafka-deploy.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: kafka
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kafka
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kafka
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: kafka
          image: bitnami/kafka
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: 9092
          env:
            - name: KAFKA_POD_IP
              valueFrom:
                fieldRef:
                  fieldPath: status.podIP
            - name: KAFKA_BROKER_ID
              value: "1"
            - name: ALLOW_PLAINTEXT_LISTENER
              value: "yes"
            - name: KAFKA_CFG_LISTENERS
              value: PLAINTEXT://:9092
            - name: KAFKA_CFG_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS
              value: PLAINTEXT://$(KAFKA_POD_IP):9092
            - name: KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP
              value: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT
            - name: KAFKA_CFG_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT
              value: zookeeper:2181

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: kafka
spec:
  selector:
    app: kafka
  ports:
    - protocol: TCP
      port: 9092
  type: LoadBalancer
```

Kafka and zookeeper configurations are more or less the same that I used with docker compose with no errors. So, probably there is something wrong in my configuration for Kubernetes. Anyone could help me please, I don't understand the issue, thanks.

Comment: Cloud you share `kubectl describe pod <kafka-pod>`? Also, you could use `kubectl logs <kafka-pod-name> -p` (the `-p` would display logs for the "previous" container -- last one to exit, rather than attach the one about to crash. could give you a better idea of what's going on)

Comment: Kafka and zookeeper are both stateful applications and should be run using a statefulset. I suggest installing it using the Helm chart https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/kafka